# Is Hibernate 4.3 @DynamicUpdate really does not include null values?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have been trying to implement entity updating using **@DynamicUpdate**. Documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/) says:

> dynamicInsert / dynamicUpdate (defaults to false): specifies that INSERT / UPDATE SQL should be generated at runtime and **contain only the columns whose values are not null**.

But I didn't manage to make it works, so I dug into the sources of AbstractEntityPersister, and saw this:

```
generateUpdateString( propsToUpdate, j, oldFields, j == 0 && rowId != null )
```

It is a method for generating SQL query string, based on 'propsToUpdate' which is boolean array obtained from:

```
getPropertiesToUpdate( dirtyFields, hasDirtyCollection );
```

where 'dirtyFields' is an integer array of id's of 'dirty' columns.

But nowhere in

```
getPropertiesToUpdate(final int[] dirtyProperties, final boolean hasDirtyCollection)
```

i was able to find mechanism for checking if modified column is not null, so even when entity i want to merge has some null fields, all of them are updated in the DB, overriding existing data with nulls.

My question is: where is an error in my reasoning?

EDIT:

Here's my code, as Chaitanya requested:

Entity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name = "t_quiz_groups")
@DynamicUpdate
@SelectBeforeUpdate
public class QuizGroupEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "group_id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
private String description;

@Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false)
@Column(name = "create_date")
private Calendar createDate;

+setters and getters
```

Then, I have a service (@Transactional) method:

```
    public void update(long groupId, String newDescription) throws ServiceException {

    QuizGroupEntity quizGroupEntity = quizRepository.getGroupById(groupId);

    ExpectedNotNull.of(quizGroupEntity, RegistryErrorCodes.QUIZ_GROUP_NOT_EXISTS);

    quizGroupEntity.setCreateDate(null); //for testing purposes i am setting another
    field as null (shouldnt be updated then, right?)

    quizRepository.lock(quizGroupEntity, LockModeType.WRITE);

    quizGroupEntity.updateDescription(newDescription); // new description

    quizRepository.merge(quizGroupEntity);


}
```

And now, in AbstractEntityPersiste, method:

```
getPropertiesToUpdate( dirtyFields, hasDirtyCollection );
```

is called, and dirtyFields[] consists of two 'dirty' columns: [0,2] - and that is correct, those two columns were modified (date and description, date set to null)

Then, generateUpdateString( propsToUpdate, j, oldFields, j == 0 && rowId != null ) is called, with 'propsToUpdate' looking like this:

```
[true, false, true, false, true]
```

Which is wrong, because indeed first and third columns were modified, but first one is set to null, that is why

```
generateUpdateString( propsToUpdate, j, oldFields, j == 0 && rowId != null )
```

Generates query:

```
[update t_quiz_groups set create_date=?, description=?, version=? where group_id=? and version=?]
```

That will modify create_date, and override it with null value.

Comment: can you please add code what you have tried and what is the query generated by hibernate that proves that `dynamicInsert / dynamicUpdate` is not working as expected?

Comment: I have provided some code in my question as You requested.

Comment: Hi, I have similar problem. I expect @DynamicUpdate to avoid trying to update null fields. But Hibernate tries to do it. I create entity and then update single field. Hibernate fails with **not-null property references a null or transient value** since I don't set NotNull column in update.